# Update value in array

Tags: objective-c, ios5

How do I update a single value in each row of my array?

For example I have an array created from an SQL DB with the following columns.

```
Name
Address
Lat
Long
Distance
```

Distance is initially set to 0 until calculated from the Lat/Long. I want to update that 0 with the calculated distance.

Every example I've found doesn't show how to update a single column per row.

```
NSMutableArray *barInfo = [BarDatabase database].barInfo;
for (Bars *info in barInfo) {
    NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@", info.barName, info.barAddress, info.Lat, info.Long, info.cachedDist);
    NSString *strLat = info.Lat;
    NSString *strLong = info.Long;
    CLLocation *barLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[strLat doubleValue] longitude:[strLong doubleValue]];
    CLLocationDistance bdistance = [currentLat distanceFromLocation:barLocation]/1000;
    [barInfo addObject:bdistance];
}
```

I'm using an NSMutableArray because I can't figure out how to modify the Distance field in the NSArray.  I know Apple states this is possible, but I can't find it.

Comment: it might be super useful to show the code of how you're currently constructing your array

Comment: I added the code that I have so far.

Comment: Can you provide information on `Bars`? The `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are just going to contain pointers to the objects of type `Bars`.   To update an individual `Bars` object, you'd be using that object's @properties.

Comment: I have an NSString "cachedDist" property in Bars.  Let me know if you need more info.